# Difference between multicopter rotor and thruster in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, usv

I'm working on a simulation in gazebo for a boat capable of omnidirectional movement. Right now I'm struggling to make thrusters work and move the boat. Just to check if multicopter rotors will move the boat I've put them instead of thrusters and made them work. Could anyone describe what is the difference in functionality between multicopter rotors and thrusters? Besides being meant for different vehicles obviously